# Why do so many libraries define their own fixed width integers?

Tags: c++, integer, fixed-width

Since at least C++11 we got lovely fixed width integers for example in C++'s `<cstdint>` or in C's `<stdint.h>` out of the box, (for example `std::uint32_t`, `std::int8_t`), so with or without the `std::`  in front of them and even as macros for minimum widths (`INT16_C`, `UINT32_C` and so on).

Yet we have do deal with libraries every day, that define their own fixed width integers and you might have seen for example `sf::Int32`, `quint32`, `boost::uint32_t`, `Ogre::uint32`, `ImS32`, ... I can go on and on if you want me to. You too know a couple more probably.

Sometimes these typedefs (also often macro definitions) may lead to conflicts for example when you want to pass a `std` fixed width integer to a function from a library expecting a fixed width integer with exactly the same width, but defined differently.

The point of fixed width integers is them having a fixed size, which is what we need in many situations as you know. So why would all these libraries go about and typedef exactly the same integers we already have in the C++ standard? Those extra defines are sometimes confusing, redundant and may invade your codebase, which are very bad things. And if they don't have the width and signedness they promise to have, they at least sin against the principle of least astonishment, so what's their point I hereby ask you?

Comment: What if you want your type to `abort()` on multiplication overflow? What if you want to support systems without `cstdint`? etc. I.e. additional features and compatibility.

Comment: One reason would be so that ADL works.  ADL only works when the types and the functions are in the same namespace.

Comment: @NathanOliver: could you expand the ADL acronym for non-native English speakers?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch [Argument-dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why do so many libraries define their own fixed width integers?

Probably for some of the reasons below:

- they started before C++11 or C11 (examples: [GTK](https://gtk.org/), [Qt](https://qt.io/), libraries internal to [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), [Boost](https://boost.org/), [FLTK](https://fltk.org/), [GTKmm](https://gtkmm.org/), [Jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp), [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org), [Dlib](http://dclib), [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/), [Wt](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt))
- they want to have readable code, within their own `namespace` or `class` (having their own namespace, like Qt does, may improve readability of well written code).
- they are build-time configurable (e.g. with [GNU autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/)).
- they want to be compilable with old C++ compilers (e.g. some C++03 one)
- they want to be [cross-compilable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler) to cheap embedded [microcontrollers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcontroller) whose compiler is not a full C++11 compiler.
- they may have generic code (or `template`-s, e.g. in  [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org) or [Dlib](http://dclib)) to perhaps support [arbitrary-precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) (or bignums) perhaps using [GMPlib](https://gmplib.org/).
- they want to be somehow provable with [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) or [DO-178C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DO-178C) certified (for embedded critical software systems)
- they are processor specific (e.g. [asmjit](https://asmjit.com/) which generates machine code at runtime on a *few* architectures)
- they might interface to specific hardware or programming languages ([Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/), [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL), [Cuda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA)).
- they want to be usable from [Python](https://python.org/) or [GNU guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/).
- they could be operating-system specific.
- they add some additional runtime checks, e.g. against division by 0 (or other undefined behavior) or overflow (that the C++ standard cannot require, for performance or historical reasons)
- they are intended to be *easily* usable from *machine-generated* C++ code (e.g. [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/), [ANTLR](https://antlr.org/), ...)
- they are designed to be callable from C code (e.g. [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/)).
- etc... Finding other good reasons is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Okay, you win. I'll stop rolling my eyes every time I see one.

Comment: I have so much code matching the first bullet point it's not funny.

Comment: I would just add that asmjit moved to C++11 and uses <stdint.h>.

I think the biggest reason why so many libraries define their own standard types is because MSVC didn't provide <stdint.h> in the past. It was really pain to do anything cross-platform without <stdint.h> so defining types that didn't conflict with it was almost always the easiest way of writing portable code.

The situation now got better, but... you cannot simply remove types that are part of the API of some library.